# Difference between throwing GeneratorExit and calling close() in python

Tags: python, generator

Thank you for opening my question. I tried to make my question clear but if there are still unclear parts because of my English, please let me know.

I am studying on Python coroutine and have read that calling a `close()` method on generator is similar to throwing `GeneratorExit` to the generator. So I tried like below.

```py
def gen(n):
    while True:
        yield n

test = gen(10)
next(test)
test.throw(GeneratorExit)
```

Then `GeneratorExit` exception occurred. However when I tried `test.close()`, it did not raise any exception.

So I modified above code slightly;

```py
def gen(n):
    while True:
        try:
            yield n
        except GeneratorExit:
            break
test = gen(10)
next(test)
test.throw(GeneratorExit)
```

As `GeneratorExit` was handled, it was not raised but `StopIteration` exception occurred. I understand that if there is no more yield, `StopIteration` exception rises. However it was not raised when I tried `test.close()` again with the modified code.

Could you let me know what the difference between throwing `GeneratorExit` and calling `close()` method is?

To be more precise, I can understand why `StopIteration` and `GeneratorExit` exception occur with `test.throw(GeneratorExit)` but don't know why those exceptions are not raised when using `test.close()`

Thanks.

Comment: You have to reraise the exception in the `except` block. Simple `break` does not handle the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it, but I raised GeneratorExit again like the unmodified code I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeneratorExit` occurs in one of two cases:

- When you're calling `close`
- When python calls the garbage collector for that generator.

(see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close))

You can see that in the following code:

```
def gen(n):
    while True:
        try:
            yield n
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("gen caught a GeneratorExit exception")
            break # (throws a StopIteration exception)

def gen_rte(n):
    while True:
        try:
            yield n
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("gen_rte caught a GeneratorExit exception")
            # No break here - we'll get a runtime exception

test = gen(10)
print(next(test))
==> 10

test.close()
==> gen caught a GeneratorExit exception  


test = gen(15)
print(next(test))
==> 15
test.throw(GeneratorExit)
```

==> 
      gen caught a GeneratorExit exception
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "...", line 20, in 
          test.throw(GeneratorExit)
      StopIteration (this is the result of the 'break' statement

```
test = gen_rte(20)
print(next(test))
==> 20

test.close()
==> 
    gen_rte caught a GeneratorExit exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "...", line 24, in <module>
        test.close()
    RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

Finally, there's another `GeneratorExit` exception before the program ends - I believe it's a result of the garbage collector. 
    gen_rte caught a GeneratorExit exception
    Exception ignored in: 
    RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit